# How to write the functionality in generics.ListAPIView which can be written in APIView in Django DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have a function base view which get 2 parameters from URL
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contest/0b36d92a-51a7-4752-9df1-e5f2733116c1/paintings/

```
@api_view(['GET',])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def Contest_detail_by_id_and_category(request, id, category_name):
 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        artcontests = Artwork.objects.filter(artcontest = id,category__name__iexact=category_name)
        serializer = ArtworkSerializer(artcontests, many=True)
        # serializer = ArtworkSerializer(artcontests, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

which give proper result , but when I try to write the same functionality in generics.ListAPIView it gives

TypeError at /api/v1/contesty/0b36d92a-51a7-4752-9df1-e5f2733116c1/paintings/
object of type 'method' has no len()

```
class Contest_detail_by_id_category(generics.ListAPIView):

 
    serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer1(many=True)
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    
    def queryset(self):
 
        queryset = Artwork.objects.filter(artcontest = self.kwargs['id'],category__name__iexact=self.kwargs['category_name'])
     
        # queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = ArtworkSerializer1(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Can anyone help me - how to write the correct view in **generics.ListAPIView** or **viewsets.ModelViewSet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `many=True` from `serializer_class`. Create `get_queryset` function as below, instead of your `queryset` function.

```py
class Contest_detail_by_id_category(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer1
    queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(artcontest = self.kwargs['id'],category__name__iexact=self.kwargs['category_name'])
```

Update: Working:
ListAPIView class inherits ListModelMixin.

```py
class ListModelMixin:
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

See  here. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py

Comment: how does it return serialized result - I tried serializer = ArtworkSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer) 

but it  gives object of type 'Response' has no len() as Error

Comment: many=True happens under the hood. Because of `ListAPIView` class

Comment: If your urls and other code is okay, then  this is supposed to work.

Comment: my bad that work - but how is the serialized data passes as response? I am just unable to understand the concept

Comment: So, the solution worked? And you only want to know how it works?

Comment: yes, it worked- also want to understand how it worked, would be great if you explain in brief. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yes, I did except